# Creating a background with stars

Tags: node-editor, shaders, camera, image, world

I know the stuff with the noise texture and the colorramp but when moving the camera something looks kinda off. When searching for this I heard terms like "infinte background" and stuff like that but I really don't know what I should do now. Is there a correct way to display the background or am I just crazy

Comment: Drop us a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

does it help?

noise texture + color ramp + background + world output
(applied to world, not a mesh)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is a parallax effect. Although I don't know how to accomplish this in a straight World Environment shader, you can "fake" the look by using transparent spheres surrounding your scene.

[image: Spheres1]

All that's necessary is to give the World Environment a simple starfield background, similar to the method you described, except I used a Voronai Texture instead of Noise.

[image: StarField]

I then used (almost) the same texture on the spheres, the only difference is the texture coordinate and the scale. I know it's hard to see from the image, but I have the color connected to the Emission in addition to the Alpha on the Principled BSDF. Therefore,  I also made sure to change the blend modes on the right to respect the alpha.

[image: StarSpheres]

The result from outside should look like this:

[image: StarSpheres2]

When moving, this is the view (pardon the short, bad video - the upload size limit prevents anything better)

[image: MovingStars]

Comment: hm. Thanks for the replies. I think I will combine some methods